# Создание новых XML элементов с помощью jQuery

Tags: xml, jquery

Есть вот такая структура xml разметки:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="93mm" height="53mm">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="white" />
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart" />
            <text x="20" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
            <text x="100" y="100" font-family="" font-size="">Кукарамба</text>
</svg>
```

И есть HTML форма! Допустим я ввел в поле `input type="text"` слово `"Хэшкод"`, как мне создать такой тэг - `<text x="100" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20px">Хэшкод</text>` и добавить перед закрывающимся тегом `</svg>`? Реализовывать данную задачу планирую с помощью jQuery.

Comment: Значение атрибутов x, y, font-family и font-size также планирую получать из полей формы.. Но что-то не могу, пока-что, сообразить как это реализовать. С Canvas'ом все было на много проще, но нужна векторная графика, а не растровая, поэтому от Canvas пришлось отказаться!

Comment: Неужели никто не может ответить на этот вопрос... жаль!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно ешё так сделать:

```
var elem = $('<text/>')
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y",100)
  .attr("font-family","Verdana")
  .attr("font-size","20px")
  .text($("#you_input_id").val());

$('svg').append(elem);
```

Прочитал комментарий [[[[[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) и его [ссылку](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) нашёл вот это:

> Unsupported in IE:
>
> $('< input />', {
>     type: 'text',
>     name: 'test' }).appendTo("body");
>
> Supported workaround:
>
> $('< input type="text" />').attr({
>     name: 'test' }).appendTo("body");

Так что **МОЙ** красивый вариант будет (хотя верхняя цитата к данному случаю не относиться, как сказал [[[[[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) и я с ним согласен):

```
var elem = $('<text/>');
elem.attr(
  {
    "x":100,
    "y":100,
    "font-family":"Verdana",
    "font-size":"20px"
  }).text($("#you_input_id").val());
  $('svg').append(elem);
```

А можно оформить в виде [плагина](http://xdan.ru/Kak-napisat-plagin-na-jQuery.html), как любит [[[[[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre), и использовать записm типа:

```
$("input").each(function(){ $('svg').append($(this).toSvgTags());});
```

Comment: некрасиво:

    var elem = $('<text/>', {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        font-family: 'Verdana',
        font-size: '20px'
    })...

[jQuery( html, props )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что так можно

Comment: >как любит @Spectre

Spectre бы использовал `backbone` везде, даже, где он не нужен, так что его слушать опасно=)

>Unsupported in IE:...

утверждение верно только для инпутов

>Internet Explorer will not allow you to create an input or button element and change its type;...

Comment: Да, согласен, но по мне, логически верно будет всё же указать что перечисляемые нами имена - это именно атрибуты тега.

Comment: разница ничтожна, главное, что атрибуты указаны ввиде хэша, особенно, когда их больше одного

Comment: Огромное Вам, спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы реализовывал с помощью [темплейтов](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

```
var tmpl = '<text x="100" y="100" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20px"><%= text %></text>';

var result = _.template(tmpl, { text : $('input').val() });

$('svg').append(result);
```

Таким же образом можно было динамически назначить и другие аргументы `x, y, font-family, etc...`